# Delimit records PHP

Tags: php, delimiter

If I have a while loop that retrieve records, I want to be able to delimit records by wrapping them after an amount of records while the loop is going, e.g.

*(using a while loop):*

```
Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
Record 4
Record 5
Record 6
Record 7
```

But I need to group records like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
</div>
<div class="wrap">
Record 4
Record 5
Record 6
</div>
Record 7
```

So when it exceeds more than 3 it should wrap every 3 count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$index = 0;

while (...) {
    if ($index == 0) {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
    } elseif (($index % 3) == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="wrap">';
    }

    // Output your stuff

    $index++;
}

if ($index != 0) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Dummy data
$records = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');

// While we have at least 3 records, group them
while (count($records) > 3) {
     $subs = array_splice($records,0,3);
     print '<div class="wrap">'.implode(PHP_EOL, $subs).'</div>';
}

// Dump the rest
print implode(PHP_EOL, $records)

?>
```